# Rails 4 join group by query for sum amount as per currency and count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

Hello I had given query

```
refund1  =  Spree::Order.joins(:refunds).group('currency').sum(:total)
=> {"USD"=>#<BigDecimal:7f896ea15ed8,'0.17641E4',18(18)>, "SGD"=>#<BigDecimal:7f896ea15d98,'0.11184E3',18(18)>, "EUR"=>#<BigDecimal:7f896ea15ca8,'0.1876E3',18(18)>} 
2.2.1 :212 > 
refund1  =  Spree::Order.joins(:refunds).group('currency').count
=> {"USD"=>2, "SGD"=>1, "EUR"=>2} 
refund1.each do |k,v| refund1[k]=[v,refund2[k]] end


=> {"USD"=>[2, #<BigDecimal:7f896f1d83a0,'0.17641E4',18(18)>], "SGD"=>[1, #<BigDecimal:7f896f1d3fa8,'0.11184E3',18(18)>], "EUR"=>[2, #<BigDecimal:7f896f1d3aa8,'0.1876E3',18(18)>]}
```

refund1  =  Spree::Order.joins(:refunds).group('currency').sum(refund.amount)

this is not working i need to sum refund amount not an order total

I need to fetch date also i.e on 02-08-2017  two  orders refunded of 100USD
Please guide me how to fetch that.

Answer (score 0):

Rails/ActiveRecord are good for relatively easy groupings, and you can group on multiple attributes instead of just the `currency`, but applying a function to one of the grouped values and returning multiple aggregations (sum and count) requires some effort.

It will also not be very performant unless you either start specifying SQL fragments in your select clause `select("date_trunc(...), currency, sum(...), count(...)")` or start using Arel (which to me always looks more complex than SQL with very few redeeming benefits).

I (because I am quite a SQL-ey person) would be tempted here to place a database view in the system that defines the aggregations that you want at the grouping level you want, and reference that in Rails through a model.

```
Create View spree_refund_day_currency_agg as select ....;
```

... and ...

```
class Spree::RefundDayCurrencyAgg < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name
    spree_refund_day_currency_agg
  end

  def read_only?
    true
  end

  belongs_to ....
end
```

You can then access your aggregated data in the Rails environment as if it were a magically maintained set of data (similar to a materialised view, without the materialisation) in a totally flexible manner (as intended with an RDBMS) using logic defined in Rails.

For example, with scopes defined in the model

```
def self.bad_day_in_canada
  where(currency: CANADA_CURR)
end
```

Not to everyone's taste though, I'm sure.